# What files should I git for my Spring boot project

Tags: java, git, spring-boot

I have done my first project using spring boot, I like it :)

But now, I have several files, that I don't know if I have to git it or ignore it

```
.classpath
.project
.gradle/5.6.2/*
.gradle/*
.settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs
bin/main/*
build/class/java/main/com/.../*.class
build/libs/snapshot.jar
build/reports/test/test/*
build/resources/main
```

Can you tell me which one should I include in my VCS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear answer to your question because it depends on whether *you* want them to be committed or not :) but...

- `.gradle` is a folder that includes settings for building your project. Deleting it is safe, because Gradle will generate it again anyway
- `bin` is usually where the compiled Java classes are copied to
- `build` is where Gradle generates all build artifacts
- `.settings` is where Eclipse stores its preferences files
- `.project` if I'm not mistaken, this file is also related to Eclipse and describes the project somehow
- `.classpath` maintains the project's source and target references for Java compilation

All the files above can be regenerated. For example, Gradle is probably generating the `.classpath` for you, while `.project` is generated by Eclipse.

Regarding `build` and `bin`, there's no good reason to commit them

I can't make the decision for you, but instead of you, I would ignore all of the files you've mentioned.